# Single Element Regex

Tags: regex

For refactoring some reasonably large classes (in Eclipse use search and replace with regex), I need to replace every array with one element with the element. The code looks roughly like this:

```
Opcodes = { IF_FCMPEQ }
```

and I want to replace it with this:

```
Opcode = IF_FCMPEQ
```

My regex currently looks like this: `Opcodes\ =\ \{ [???] \}`, but I don't know what to put between the (escaped) curly brackets. The text between the brackets is in all cases a single identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find What:

```
(Opcodes = )\{ (\w+) \}
```

`\w+` matches one or more word characters.

Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/16)

If you want only `Opcode` in the final result instead of `Opcodes` then use this,

Find what:

```
Opcodes = \{ (\w+) \}
```

Replace With:

```
Opcode = \1
```

Comment: `\1\2` did not replace `Opcodes` with `Opcode`, but I figured out that `Opcode = \2` does the job. Thanks anyway.

Comment: oh yes, i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `\w+`, which means "one or more word characters".

Java defines "word characters" as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, which is what you can use in Java identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Does `(.+)` or `(\w+)` work for that case under consideration.